# BigQuery select value from 2 tables based on condition

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I have two tables - bookingcom and accomodation.
I want to get data until 1.7. from table accomodation and since 1.7. from bookingcom

I tried to achieve it with code:

```
    SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN DATE(created) <= DATE("2015-07-01") THEN [ROI:ROI_accomodation.created]
    ELSE [ROI:bookingcom.created]
    END AS date
    FROM
    ROI.bookingcom,
    ROI.ROI_accomodation
```

But I get following error:

```
 Field 'ROI:bookingcom.created' does not exist in any union input schema.
```

Could you help, where I am making mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your mistake is that your `case when then` statement requires a choice between those two tables on each line, which is only possible if you join them, but instead you took their union.

My impression is that you don't really need both tables for the same date, you simply need the first table up until 1 July (I'm assuming you want 1 July and not 7 January), and then the second table. If that is correct, you could do something like

```
from
(select column1,column2,column3 from ROI:bookingcom where date(created) <= date('2015-07-01')),
(select column1,column2,column3 from ROI:ROI_accomodation where date(created) > date('2015-07-01'))
```